# How to add Windows 10 optional fonts programmatically?

Tags: fonts, windows-10

windows 10 has feature called Manage Optional Features that allows you to add some nice new fonts. They have a UI to manage it. Is there a way to turn this on programmatically for our users so that they are available in our app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature in Windows 10 is called [Capabilities (Features On Demand V2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/desktop/features-on-demand-v2--capabilities)

To see all available Capabilities, open [a cmd prompt as admin](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2790-elevated-command-prompt-open-windows-10-a.html) and run this DISM command:

```
DISM /Online /Get-Capabilities
```

Now you can enable or disable 1 one the Capabilities with DISM:

```
DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-Fonts-Thai-Package

DISM.exe /Online /Remove-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft-Windows-LanguageFeatures-Fonts-Thai-Package
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ivan/2c2b493729faacf08c3e7a090e57a236